# Q: Serve audio files ini web api 2

Tags: c#, audio, asp.net-web-api2

I want to write a webapi2 controller (in C#) which is able to return audio files. What is the best/right approach? Do I also need to consider range requests (like for videos)?
The audio file should be consumed by a standard html5 audio tag.
Thanks for your recommendations

Comment: You need to return the correspondent byte array content followed by the appropiate HTTP headers for the client to actually understand your response, i.e., `ContentType = "audio/mpeg"`, `ContentLength = byteArray.Length`, etc.

Comment: Allowing range requests will never hurt you and since ASP.NET has built-in support for that it would be silly to not just use that.

Comment: @Sami: what do you mean ASP.NET has built-in support?